# How can i format a json body in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to declare a json body in powershell as follows:

```
$body= @{
    Id = "123"
    SessionId =""
    Sorting = [{ field = "EventDateTime", dir = "desc" }]
    Group = []
}
```

The issue is the

```
Sorting = [{ field = "EventDateTime", dir = "desc" }]    and the 
Group = []
```

How can i format these in powershell before invoking a request ?

Comment: To create a PowerShell expression from your Json string, you might use this [ConvertTo-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) cmdlet. E.g.: `'{"Id":123,"SessionId":"","Sorting":[{"field":"EventDateTime","dir":"desc"}],"Group":[]}' | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Expression`

Answer (score 0):

`[ ]` is an array in Json strings, to translate it to PowerShell you can use the [array subexpression operator `@()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#array-subexpression-operator--) then `{ }` is an object, in PowerShell you can use [`[ordered]@{ }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-7.0) or [`[pscustomobject]@{ }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3) if you need to preserve the order of the key value pairs  or [`@{ }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) if you don't care about that.

```
$body = [ordered]@{
    Id        = 123
    SessionId = ''
    Sorting   = @(
        [ordered]@{
            field = 'EventDateTime'
            dir   = 'desc'
        }
    )
    Group     = @()
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: @Angela I added the links to the corresponding docs

Comment: @Angela I dont know what you mean