# How can i format a json body in c#?

Tags: c#

How can i format the following into a json body in c# ?

```
    {
    id = "123"
    SessionId =""
    Sorting = [{ field = "EventDateTime", dir = "desc" }]
    Group = []
   }
```

I would usually declare

```
     var body = new
    {

       id = "123" ,
       SessionId =""
      ???
   }
request.AddJsonBody(body);
```

But these 2 are not formatting correctly

```
Sorting = [{ field = "EventDateTime", dir = "desc" }]
    Group = []
```

Comment: That seems to be json. What do you mean by "formatting into json body"?

Comment: Does that mean, you need a model that you can serialize, so that the serialzed JSON looks like this?

Comment: I am sending it in the body with the request

Comment: Well, obviously not now, since this is not valid JSON.

Comment: `Sorting` seems to be a collection of objects that have the properties `field` and `dir`. And `Group` seems to be a Collection of unknown type but my _guess_ would be string.

Comment: So it's [How can i format a json body in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76536880/205233) all over again.

Comment: No , how to format in c# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .NET `JsonSerializer` from `System.Text.Json` namespace with specifying `JsonSerializerOptions`:

```
class Sample { public string Prop1 { get; set; } public string Prop2 { get; set; } }

var s = new Sample { Prop1 = "value1", Prop2 = "value2" };
Console.Write(JsonSerializer.Serialize(s, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }))
```

Here's example using csharprepl:
[image]

**UPDATE**

Given example from question this could be achieved with:

```
dynamic sorting = new { field = "EventDateTime", dir = "desc" };
dynamic d = new { id = "123", SessionId = "", Sorting = new[] { sorting }, Group = Array.Empty<object>() };
Console.Write(JsonSerializer.Serialize(d, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }));
```

And the output:
[image]

Comment: is there an example of this ?

Comment: @Angela I attached picture with result.

Comment: so would you be able to use the example i gave above still cant get tit to work ?

Answer (score 0):

[Raw string literal text - """ in string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/raw-string)

```
var formatted_json = """
{
    "id" = "123"
    "SessionId" = ""
    "Sorting" = [{ "field" = "EventDateTime", "dir" = "desc" }]
    "Group" = []
}
""";
```

Comment: doesnt work .. its in c#

Comment: The answer _is_ in C#.